# ImportError: No module named 'pyRserve'

Tags: python, r, importerror

I am getting the error

> "ImportError: No module named 'pyRserve'" during installation of a program, but pyRserve is already installed.
>   Requirement already satisfied: pyRserve in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
>   Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pyRserve)
>   Requirement already satisfied: pytest in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pyRserve)
>   Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pytest->pyRserve)
>   Requirement already satisfied: py>=1.4.33 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pytest->pyRserve)

Can someone help me in this regard

Comment: It seems pyRserve is installed to your 2.7 distribution, are you trying to import it within the 2.7 interpretor or do you have multiple python installations?

Comment: I have got multiple python installation: /usr/bin/python2.7 and /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.5. I changed the .bashrc and set the python to /usr/bin/python3 but still if I type on command prompt for python version it says Python 2.7.12. Thanks

Comment: I tried the command I am getting an error  "python3 pip -m install pyRserve"
python3: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory".

Comment: Sorry it's 'python2 -m pip install pyRserver' or 'python3 -m pip install pyRserver'

Comment: I tried this command which finally worked "sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pyRserve"

Comment: now if you do 'python3' and when the interactive shell opens do 'import pyRserve' it should import